# importing python package in virtual environment

Tags: python, macos

I have macOS Serria and I want to import installed python package. I created virtual environment by:

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python2.7 my_virtual
```

Then, I activate my_virtual and made sure I use the same pip and python in my_virtual. I installed pydicom in my_virtual by:

```
pip install pydicom
```

However, when I want to import pydicom in python in my_virtual I can not and I get the following error.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 25 2017, 09:53:22) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pydicom
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pydicom
```

I think I have followed all instructions on web, so what should I do now?

Comment: After activating your virtual env, what happens when you run `which python`?  Does the output correspond to what you'd expect?  How about running `which pip` after activating your venv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to activate the virtual environment before installing the python package using `pip` by running:

```
$ source my_virtual/bin/activate
```

After installing your python packages in the virtual environment, you have to deactivate it my running:

```
$ deactivate
```

Try importing into python again. I hope this helps.

## Update:

Run:

```
import dicom
```

Please see [Getting Started with pydicom](http://pydicom.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html)